# Firebase only shows events logged in last 30 minutes - How to get all the events logged

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

For an event logged in my game (not a custom event but the `LEVEL_START` event provided by Firebase Analytics) I cant seem to see all the events logged. Anything older than 30 minutes I cannot see.

[image]

Is there a way to see all the events logged against this event name?